# Compiling mono project with command-line tools

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I've been working with MonoDevelop for some time, but want to try other editors. How can I replace MonoDevelop's build capabilities with Mono's command line tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways,

- `mdtool` - gets installed by monodevelop.
- `xbuild` - part of mono and does the same thing as `msbuild`.